# How to run .NET 4.6.1 framework unit tests from command line

Tags: .net, unit-testing, command-line

Is it possible to run .NET 4.6.1 framework unit tests from a command line?

I've tried this command on a new MSTest unit test project, target framework .NET 4.6.1:

```
C:\test\Project.Test2>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 38C3-41EF

 Directory of C:\test\Project.Test2

10/19/2022  05:21 PM    <DIR>          .
10/19/2022  03:24 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/19/2022  03:24 PM    <DIR>          bin
10/19/2022  03:24 PM    <DIR>          obj
10/19/2022  05:17 PM               230 packages.config
10/19/2022  03:24 PM    <DIR>          Properties
10/19/2022  05:21 PM             4,961 Project.Test2.csproj
10/19/2022  05:13 PM               398 UnitTest1.cs
               3 File(s)          5,589 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  100,299,866,112 bytes free

C:\test\Project.Test2>dotnet test
  Determining projects to restore...
  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
```

Unit test file content:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Project.Test2
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see unit test command invocation doesn't return any result about passed or failed unit tests. Could you please how should I change the command to get a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it by installing `xunit.runner.visualstudio` and `xunit.runner.console` from NuGet Package Manager. After that (didnt even restart the IDE) it worked like a charm.

I used the following command in console:

```
dotnet test UnitTestProject1.sln --logger "html;LogFileName=TestResults.html"
```